# How to obtain and install shc?

Tags: software-installation, scripts, compiler

shc is a compiler that compiles bash scripts into Linux executables. However, I can't find an official site and can't find it in the Ubuntu repos either. What is the official site, and why is it not in the repos? What is the recommended way to install shc in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will help you installing/using **shc**:

- https://github.com/existz/shc-3.8.9

Comment: The same source is apparently also available, packed in a .tar.gz archive, at http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/shc-3.8.9.tgz.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [this version of shc](https://github.com/neurobin/shc) by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:neurobin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shc
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answers didn't work for me... Or at least shc version 3.8.9b didn't work (the binaries it created would just hang), and that's what "sudo apt install shc" installed.

Here's how I got it to work.

1. Download the [the latest version of shc](https://github.com/neurobin/shc/releases), currently 4.0.3.
2. Open a terminal and cd to your downloads directory, or wherever the tar file is.
3. Extract it:

   ```
   $ tar xvfz shc-4.0.3.tar.gz  # depending on version
   ```
4. Then do the installation:

   ```
   $ ./configure
   ...
   $ make
   ...
   $ sudo make install
   ...
   ```

You're done! Try it out with a [simple example](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/).